# Magento add product for different storeview in one step

Tags: magento

currently when I add or edit products for magento via api I will do something like this for each storeview:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->setStoreId($default_store_id); // 0 = default/all store view. 

// do something

try 
{
   $product->save();
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

This will takes 1 second for each storeview. When I edit 1 product for 10 storeviews it will takes 10 seconds.

Is there any way to edit alle storeview data (different languages) in one step?

Answer (score 1):

No is the simple answer. You can create optimised code though for editing and only save the attribute you are updating as opposed to the entire product object but this depends on the scenario you are catering for.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($product_id);
$product->setName('Product Name');
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'name');
```

Other option is to work directly on the database for updates rather than use magento objects.